# ASP.NET Two Threads, one Result

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I need to run TWO Threads in a web application, .NET. 3.5

Both methods MakeRedCars and MakeBlueCars need to run at the same time as both take 5 seconds. I have tried many example codes with very bad results. I dont need anymore than 2 threads. The main issue I am having is knowing how to wait till they are finished and also how to store the results from each.

Each of the Methods do different things, one is a web request, one is a sql call.

Both methods return a list of(cars) for example do:

```
carList.addrange(MakeRedCars())
carList.addrange(MakeBlueCars())

for each car in carlist<br>
    response.write(car.colour + "<\br>")
next
```

I have implemented the answered below and with empty objects all works well, as soon as you hook in a database call that returns the data/objects studio does a JIT and crashes.

Comment: .NET 4 or .NET3.5 (or lower)? It makes a difference.

Comment: Tejs, do u have a idea ?

Comment: @mark - .NET 4 has the Task Parallel Library (TPL) - which would make implementing this trivial.

Comment: unfortunately only have vs2008

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply add the list using a javascript call directly? I always prefer to handle the async stuff in the HTML code rather than directly on the Server...

BTW, what is `carList` a Dropdown? `<asp:ListBox>`

try this:

**1 - The Server side**

Create a Generic Handler and drop your call there, then return the list in some kind of array, or do it all there, it's up to you, personally I prefer to send JSON from my Handlers (I call them My Background Workers)

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="GetListA" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class GetListA : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        string myType = Request["type"];

        //Do your call and fill up carlist

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        foreach (var car in carlist) {
            sb.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", 
                                 car.colourId, 
                                 car.colourName);
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**2 - The javascript call**

Create a method that calls your List, to reuse the method, let's pass a variable

```
function getListAsync(elem, param) {

    $.get("myGetList.ashx", {type:param}, function(data) {
        if(data.length > 0)
            $("#" + elem).empty().append(data);
    });

}
```

then simply call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getListAsync("myListA", "A");
    getListAsync("myListB", "B");
}
```

I hope this helps do what you need in an asynchronous mode from now on

Comment: Good but it needs to be server side for SEO stuff, when it renders the result.

Comment: then you should cache the result and place that in the description as a constant value, crawlers dont wait 5 sec to see results, just simply read the headers and move on...

Comment: car list is a list(of object)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Join` on a plain old thread. `Join` will block the current thread until that thread is finished.

The trick is being able to get the results of them and merge them together in a thread-safe manner.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim t1 = New Thread(AddressOf MakeBlueCars)
    Dim t2 = New Thread(AddressOf MakeRedCars)
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
    t1.Join() 'Wait till t1 is done
    t2.Join() 'Wait till t2 is done
    'The field cars will contain the results here.
End Sub

Private cars As List(Of Car) = New List(Of Car)()

Sub MakeBlueCars()
    Dim blueCars = New List(Of Car)()
    'Populate blueCars
    SyncLock cars
        cars.AddRange(blueCars)
    End SyncLock

End Sub

Sub MakeRedCars()
    Dim redCars = New List(Of Car)()
    'Populate redCars
    'Merge the thread-specific list with the main list, blocking only once instead of every time a car is added.
    SyncLock cars
        cars.AddRange(redCars)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to wait until both threads are finished and you should use two collections instead of one for both threads, because it's expensive to synchronize both if not really needed:

```
Dim redThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MakeRedCars)
Dim blueThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MakeBlueCars)
redThread.Start()
blueThread.Start()
redThread.Join()
blueThread.Join()
Dim carList = New List(Of String)(redCars)
carlist.AddRange(blueCars)
For Each car In carList
    Response.Write(car)
Next
```

....

```
Private redCars As New List(Of String)
Private blueCars As New List(Of String)

Private Sub MakeRedCars()
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 100000
        redCars.Add("Car #" & i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MakeBlueCars()
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 100000
        blueCars.Add("Car #" & i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dont have access to the new Task Parallel Library (.NET 4) i guess you use te Thread class.

You can wait for thread completion with the `Thread.Join()` method.
So you spin up your two threads and join them both:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(func1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(func2);
List<Car> l1 = new List<Car>();
List<Car> l2 = new List<Car>();

// start them
t1.Start(l1);
t1.Start(l2);

// join them
t1.Join();
t2.Join();

// now you have your two lists populated with cars
```

To get your result you could use some shared fields in your class or you might give a state-object to your threads.

Comment: Not difficult to convert but tagged as VB.NET

Comment: @Tim: Oh yes, you are right. I think i have a blind spot when i read VB.NET :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ThreadStart tsMakeRedCars  = new ThreadStart(MakeRedCars);
Thread tMakeRedCars = new Thread(tsMakeRedCars  );
tMakeRedCars .Start();

ThreadStart tsMakeBlueCars  = new ThreadStart(MakeBlueCars);
Thread tMakeBlueCars = new Thread(tsMakeBlueCars  );
tMakeBlueCars.Start();

tMakeRedCars.join();
tMakeBlueCars.join();

//I think this will serve, you purpose.
```